# How to convert an array of char to array of int

Tags: c

Is there a way to convert an array of char to array of int32 **without iterating every member**.

I need to convert a huge amount of data so I'm looking for some faster than:

```
char ac[1000000];
int32_t ai[1000000];
for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++) {
    ai[i]=ac[i];
}
```

**Notes:**

- I'm not asking about how to convert '3' to 0x03, I'm talking about convert 0x03 (one byte) to 0x00000003 (to  4 bytes)
- Not portable is not a problem (platform linux AMD64).
- The proposed method is slow.
- looking for a library that use SSE instructions or similar. 
  I need it to feed a math function that works with int32 numbers and my original data is in 8 bits size, so I need to convert it, and obviously I can't cast because is an memory area not a value.

Comment: have you try to search before asking ?

Comment: @stargateur yes, i did every think that I found is about convert character to its value, I don't want that.  , thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with _your_ solution? Do you think it is too slow?

Comment: The proposed way is OK. Other ways might be too hackish and non-portable.

Comment: Well, since extra 'holes' have to be put in the char data to extend it to int size, I don't see how you can do it without iterating...

Comment: Use a platform where `sizeof(signed char)` == `sizeof(int)` and hope they use the same encoding.

Comment: What would '0' ('\x48') be converted to? 0 or 48?

Comment: BTW: 1000000 chars is not really huge by today's standards.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is getting so much downvote. That "without iterating" is a crucial part of the question. So I made it bold.

Comment: You could probably parallelize it quite easily.  Kinda depends on your numbers.  Signaling, say, 4 start and finish addresses to 4 waiting threads is gonna take a couple tens us of overhead.

Comment: **Definitevely, no**. Performing an operation on every element of a data structure with arbitrary data requires as many operations as there are elements in that data structure. You may be able to implement some optimizations if your data has a pattern, but we can't assume that based off what you've posted.

Comment: @taskinoor thanks, I fill stupid, but the question is not obvious, I put 1.000.000 but actually I have to do 1.000.000 times blocks of 1.000.000, is huge and i need kind of parallelization or a library that can use CPU resources to do it in block. People that downgrade de question don have idea about what I'm talking.

Comment: Are you sure you need ints? Why not uint8_t?

Comment: @Mquinteiro I think you should edit the question with these details to avoid further confusion. Looking for some idea on whether this kind of copy can be paralleled sounds a good question to me.

Comment: Maybe this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Tell us a bit more about this requirement, Why do you need to do this conversion?

Comment: Ooh. err.. '1.000.000 times blocks of 1.000.000' thread pool for sure.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do the conversion at all?

Comment: Also, what @MichaelWalz says.  Can you give any more details of the overall requirement?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I need that because I'm using different libraries for some maths that need int32 and my original data is in char (8 bits). So I need to transform it to feed the next function. believe me, I need it. thanks.

Comment: @Mquinteiro you should put that information into the question. But if you need to do maths on the converted data, isn't that much slower than the conversion process anyway?

Comment: Do a quick test: run just your your 'convert' as a test process on a larger data set so it's easy to time, (maybe even so big it's easy to time with a stopwatch:), and run it.  The start two of the processes 'manually' and see if it takes twice as long, or significantly less than twice, (assuming you have more than one core in your CPU)..   Not a perfect test, but it may give some idea.

Comment: Also, I have to ask, does the 'maths library' need just one '1000000' chunk of ints at a time?  If so, you can maybe 'convert' and 'process' different chunks in parallel?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit lot of them, It's a satellite image I have to work with thousand of them and every one is 128MB.  Looks like you want to know everything :)

Comment: @Mquinteiro if I know everything, I can say for sure that I have no good answer:)

Comment: With 128MB chunks, (OK, more 5-course meal than chunk), I would definitely try to parallelize.. something.  It all depends on your numbers, hardware etc. Maybe a GPU array could help.

Comment: See my edit in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to convert an array of char to array of int without iterate every member.

No.

*Trying* to explain this (I assumed it would be obvious): an `int` is a different size than a `char`, so no block copies would ever help you. In one or another way, you *have* to touch each element.

There might be solutions parallelizing this, e.g. by partitioning the array and using threads to handle the parts. But you would still have to convert each and every element.

---

Regarding your edit:

> convert 0x03 (one byte) to 0x0003 (to bytes)
>   [...] not portable is not a problem (platform linux AMD64)

There seems to be another misconception: `int` on Linux x86_64 has four bytes, not two. If you really need two bytes per input value, you should use `int16_t`.

---

And yet another remark: Typical `SIMD` instructions (like in SSE2) won't help you either. They assume the same layout of input and output areas. As already stated, the only "optimization" I can possibly see is parallelizing. There's no way around having to touch each element.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thanks I know that int is bigger that char, that is the reason of the question.

Comment: @FelixPalmen actually I have to convert to an int32 but it was a code simplification to illustrate.

Comment: [GCC will use AVX and/or AVX2](https://godbolt.org/g/prJbfc) instructions to implement this loop (assuming you provide appropriate command-line optimization flags), so it may not be true that SIMD "won't help". It helps unroll the loop, for example. (But I didn't benchmark to see if GCC's optimization is actually useful.)

Comment: @rici x86 has way too many instructions, I'm lost here ;) thanks for the hint!

Comment: @rici so your proposal is to compile with -o 3 and let gcc do it's work? Cuda is another solution but a lot of to work for small award ;)

Comment: @mquinteiro : -O3 -march=native.. You should always optimize for production  code, and particularly if you care about execution time.

Comment: @rice production.... far word! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will be faster, you have to check (also it will be depend on the sizeof(int) == 4):

```
// note: untested
char ac[1000000];
int ai[1000000];
memset(ai, 0, sizeof(int) * 1000000); // this should be very fast
char * d = (char *) (ai + 3); // go to last byte of the first int
for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++) {
    d += 4; // go to last byte of the next int
    *d=ac[i];
}
```

Comment: you can do the same with ac and avoid ac[] but it still slow, thanks.

Comment: `char * d = (char *) (ai + 3);` -> `char *d = (char *)ai + 3;` (the first version goes to the first byte of the third int!)

Comment: and then, it's probably slower, I'd expect an optimizing compiler to emit some [`movzbl`](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/macvax/op-codes/Instructions/movz.html) for the original code.

Comment: @noel-lopes It the micro had 8bit data bus it is a great idea. But here don't believe that it could accelerate in 64bits platform

Comment: I'm not sure the compiler will emit a movzbl, because char is signed by default

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need ints?

If not, you could do

```
char ac[1000000];
uint8_t *ai = (uint8_t*)ac;
```

if the reason you want them to be ints is because a function takes an int as argument and you need to pass some of the values of the array to it, then there is no problem with this method, as they will be implicitly casted to ints.

I think that converting them to ints just makes you use more memory than you actually need.

EDIT:

If you actually DO need an int array, here is a workaround that does not store more than it needs.

You can make a helper function that just extracts the char value casted to an int from the newly created int array, hence behaving like an int array.

```
// Endianness test to extract the char number
constexpr bool endianness() {
    return *(int*)const_cast<char*>("\x00\x01") & 1;
}

// Get char value casted to int from the int array
int getVal(int *i, int idx) {
    int iidx = idx / sizeof(int);
    int rem = idx % sizeof(int);
    if(endianness()) rem = sizeof(int) - rem - 1;
    return (i[iidx] & (0xff << 8*rem)) >> 8*rem;
}
```

To use this you just convert the char array to an int pointer and just use it, like so.

```
char ac[1000000];
int *ai = (int*)ac;
cout << getVal(ai, 0);
```

This will print the value of the first element casted into an int and is actually portable.

Comment: Your code is wrong, but thanks.

Comment: @Mquinteiro Edited it. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I don't see the point in this pointer alias? you could just directly use `ac`...

Comment: I need change the size in memory form 1 byte to 4 bytes, that kind of cast is not valid for my problem.

Comment: I can't use that, various reasons 1) if you need to read after all the data it is sooo slow, 2) I have to pass the data block to another function. But  the answer is awesome ;)

Comment: At least i tried...

Comment: @Garmekain Sure! I appreciate!

Comment: OP posted a C question.  This answer is not C.  Casting a `char *` to `int *` is UB in C.

Comment: @chux I didn't know that. Could you point me to something where this is explained?

Comment: @Garmekain You do not know `const_cast<char*>` is not C code?

Comment: @chux Yes, but I don't know how a cast from `char*` to `int*` is UB in C.

Comment: @Garmekain "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined." §6.3.2.3 7  `char` objects and `int` objects may have different alignment requirements.